# function not working on remote server

Tags: php

the function is for checking if an url is pointing to a valid image by checking the meta info in the head section of the given file.

the echo in the below code gives me the correct wrapper data but on my remote server it echoes "ArrayResource id #11"  How this is possible?

local:PHP Version 5.3.4
remote server: PHP Version 5.2.9

```
 function isImage($url)
      {
         $params = array('http' => array(
                      'method' => 'HEAD'
                   ));
         $ctx = stream_context_create($params);
         $fp = @fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx);
         if (!$fp) 
            return false;  // Problem with url

        $meta = stream_get_meta_data($fp);
        if ($meta === false)
        {
            fclose($fp);
            return false;  // Problem reading data from url
        }

        $wrapper_data = $meta["wrapper_data"];
        if(is_array($wrapper_data)){
          foreach(array_keys($wrapper_data) as $hh){
            echo substr($wrapper_data[$hh], 0, 19);//////////////ECHO////////////////////////
              if (substr($wrapper_data[$hh], 0, 19) == "Content-Type: image") // strlen("Content-Type: image") == 19 
              {
                fclose($fp);
                return true;
              }
          }
        }

        fclose($fp);
        return false;
      }
```

EDIT: I adapted the function so it checks if 'Content-Type: image' is somewhere in the header of the file. this works cross server...

```
function isImage($url)
  {
     $params = array('http' => array(
                  'method' => 'HEAD'
               ));
     $ctx = stream_context_create($params);
     $fp = @fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx);
     if (!$fp) 
        return false;  // Problem with url

    $meta = get_headers($url);

    if ($meta === false)
    {
        fclose($fp);
        return false;  // Problem reading data from url
    }
    foreach ($meta as $key => $value) {
        $pos = strpos($value, 'Content-Type: image');
            if($pos!==false){
             fclose($fp);
             return true;
            }
    }



    fclose($fp);
    return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-meta-data.php). `stream_get_meta_data` can return values in several datatypes. On your remote server it is returning an array.

Comment: I noticed it was returning an array but I didn't know why. thank you for pointing me in a good direction!